# How can i calculate $d/dt(\partial f/\partial x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $f$ be a function of two variables such that $$x=a+th \text{ and } y=b+tk$$

Then $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)= \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$$

But where did this rule come from? It’s obvious that it is related to the chain rule but how exactly ?

Comment: Have you tried working from the definitions of total & partial derivatives?

Comment: What do you mean by total ?

Comment: See [the wiki article on the chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

What you might know is :

If $ F $ is a function of two variables $ x $ and $ y $, then
$$\boxed{dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy}$$

You just need to replace $ F(x,y) $ by
${\partial f}/{\partial x }$ and divide by $ dt $.

The equation you wrote is not correct. The last term should be $$\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$$

Comment: I don’t know the first equation you wrote, can you just give me a link so that i can see where did it come from.

Comment: @Yassir chouf " différentielle et dérivées partielles." with Goo.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Not regarding this answer, but apparently on your mobile device , if you go all the way to the bottom you will see a button called : "full site". Whenever you need to delete a question, please click on the "full site" link, and then see if the delete button now appears on the answer that you want to delete. You can click it if it appears, if it does not then let me know if I can do any debugging for you. Once you are done, you can again go back to the bottom of the screen and get the link "mobile site" from which your display is restored. Let me know if problems persist.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much.